# saddle point versus local extermum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Suppose a function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, is differentiable.
We know that $c$ is a critical point of $f$, i.e. $\nabla f(c) = 0$. Our goal is to find out if $c$ is a local extremum, or a saddle point, without computing the Hessian.

Does this suggestion work?

Take $n$ orthogonal vectors (directions) $v$ in  $\mathbb{R}^n$. Examine $f$ at $c$: If all $n$ vectors $v$s are  ascent directions, we are at a local minimum, if they are all descent directions we are at a local maximum, otherwise we are at a saddle point.

Comment: What does "examine $f$" mean, specifically? What computations are you proposing to perform, directional derivatives? If so, the answer is certainly no, since $f'(c+tv)=0$ at $t=0$ regardless of $v$.

Comment: Sentences following examine explains how I do that. I examine by checking if $n$ directions $v$ are all ascent or descent directions at $c$.

Comment: Yes. So how do you determine if a direction is an ascent or descent direction? What is your mathematical test?

Comment: It sounds like what you intend to do is to take finite differences, ie. compare f(c) with f(c+epsilon*v_i)...  is that correct?

Comment: @BadZen, that is a good suggestion. I was thinking that an oracle can tell us if the direction is ascent or descent, to decouple the correctness of suggestion from the algorithm.

Comment: It's not a suggestion - I was asking if that's what you were proposing, to clarify your question.  It's more of the opposite of a suggestion, actually...

Comment: Yes, that was the first think that came to my mind. Using finite difference.

Comment: It will not be possible to definitively conclude that a critical point is a local minimum or maximum using finite sampling. One could always construct a differentiable function that mimics the behavior of a local optimum at the sampled points but deviates at some others. For that matter, the finite difference could fail to reveal the actual behavior at a shorter distance. @BadZen seems to agree with my point: you need to be more specific about how you intend to "examine" things.

Comment: Heck, even checking the Hessian won't necessarily do it. For instance, consider $f(x)=\sum_i x_i^4$. The Hessian is zero at the origin as well.